# cross-browser print command?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, command

i want to know if there is any cross-browser print code, that is if i need other then just simple:

```
//print page
    $('.print').click(function() {
        window.print();
        return false;
    });
```

i did found for bookmark and thats why i was more concern about print too, but couldn't find anything useful on google.

following code is for bookmark cross-browser

```
//bookmark page
$("a.bookmark").click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the anchor tag from going the user off to the link
    var bookmarkUrl = this.href;
    var bookmarkTitle = this.title;

    if (window.sidebar) { // For Mozilla Firefox Bookmark
        window.sidebar.addPanel(bookmarkTitle, bookmarkUrl,"");
    } else if( window.external || document.all) { // For IE Favorite
        window.external.AddFavorite( bookmarkUrl, bookmarkTitle);
    } else if(window.opera) { // For Opera Browsers
        $("a.jQueryBookmark").attr("href",bookmarkUrl);
        $("a.jQueryBookmark").attr("title",bookmarkTitle);
        $("a.jQueryBookmark").attr("rel","sidebar");
    } else { // for other browsers which does not support
        alert('Your browser does not support this bookmark action');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: [Check this about print](http://printstylesheet.com/)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

window.print() is a de-facto standard. (it's been supported since the days of IE4/Netscape 4).

While you're at it, be sure to check out how you can customize how your page looks when it's printed using [print-specific CSS stylesheets](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/).

Comment: `window.print()` invokes nothing on Chrome if you have popup blockers :/

Comment: @balexandre - link to bug, article, or test case documenting that behavior, please.  If that's really the case, it would break a large number of websites that rely on `window.print` to implement their own print UI. :/

Comment: just try yourself! using [AdBlockPlus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb).

Comment: @balexandre - `window.print()` works as expected with both AdBlock and AdBlockPlus extensions in chrome.  Perhaps this is just an issue for you?  (Hence my request for some supporting documentation of the problem)

Comment: maybe it is just for me, even with the new Chrome v.29 I have the issue :(

Comment: It's not part of a standard. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9269238/3150057. But I see what you mean by "de-facto" as in "it's existed for a long, long time and is used pretty much everywhere."

Answer (score 2):

`window.print()` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

That is the general way. It is not an official part of the dom. I would check for its existence first.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set your html to have Content Security Policy similar to this:

```
frame-src * 'self' blob: data:
```

Example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:; frame-src * 'self' blob: data:">
```

The important part here is: frame-src blob: data:  (the blob part)

Then, you can print using a "local" non cross-domain way by setting the iframe to a load a blob instead of an "outside URL"

Using this:

```
 function printPage(url) {
      fetch(url)
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.blob();
        })
        .then(function (myBlob) {
          var newFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
          var existingDOMIframe = document.getElementById('printIframe');
          if (existingDOMIframe) {
            document.body.removeChild(existingDOMIframe);
          }

          newFrame.id = 'printIframe';
          newFrame.style.width = '0';
          newFrame.style.border = '0';
          newFrame.style.height = '0';
          newFrame.style.position = 'relative';
          var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
          newFrame.src = objectURL;
          newFrame.onload = function () {
            document.querySelector('#printIframe').contentWindow.print();
          };
          document.body.appendChild(newFrame);
          objectURL = URL.revokeObjectURL(myBlob);
        });
    }
```