# How to get window.print() to run locallly?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have been writing a website for the last couple of weeks but cannot get the Javascript function window.print() to run locally in my browser. I do not have server space yet so I cannot check the online functionality. Here is my code:

```
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Print this page" onclick="window.print();" />
    </form>
```

Does anyone know if this function can run on a local machine? Or is there a problem with my code? Thanks

Comment: it works locally for me

Comment: Works just fine for me. [Here's a fiddle with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/7UQMJ/). What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: This is probably a browser issue rather than an issue with your code

Comment: Nothing happens when I click the button, I have tried in firefox and chrome and nothing happens in either of them. Firebug does not detect an error too so I dont knwo what is wrong. Is there a script I have to include for it to work?

Comment: Just tried it there on a new page with no information and it worked, must be a problem with the page I have developed.

Comment: there must be a javascript error somewhere else on the page thats the only thing that would prevent javascript like that working however the fact that it worked after an `alert` is a bit strange as that would say there is no error. is there any other javascript in the page before it? including analytics codes

Comment: no the rest of my JavaScript, including analytics, is in the bottomof the body. It's very strange when I take out all the content and just leave the button it works fine, but when I have the content in it won't work, very strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is fine.  It should work.

You might also want to try onclick="javascript:window.print();" and see if that works.

Another option you can try then is to create a function inside a script tag and call it from your onclick event:

```
<input type="button" value="Print this page" onclick="PrintMe()" />

<script>
    function PrintMe(){
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I thought that was used in anchor tags. Can it be used in regular event handlers as well?

Comment: I have tried that in an anchor tag and tried the normal call in buttons to no avail.

Comment: Are you able to run any javascript code?  You might want to run an alert("test"); inside a document.ready to see if for some reason you have javascript turned off on your browser

Comment: Yes if I put an alert function before or after the print() function it runs, it's very strange. Is there someway I can post the whole page code? I dont want to post it in the question

Comment: Oh, and by the way... this may seem like a silly question but do you have any printers defined on your computer?

Comment: I tried putting it in a seperate function and yeah I have printers defined on the computer, thanks though! Is there somewhere I can post the full page code? It's around 200 lines

Answer (score 1):

It might be a problem with the form tag..

try using button without form requirement

```
<button onclick="window.print();">Print this page</button>
```

Or if you are using the form

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Print this page" onclick="window.print();return false;" />
</form>
```

if alert works and then enables this to work what happens if you try

```
onclick="console.log(window.print());return false;"
```

Comment: tried it with buttons and anchor tags, nothing works, thanks though.

Comment: if your using IE 9 or newer. press F12, if your in FF or Chrome right click inspect Element and then for them all click the console tab.

Answer (score 0):

Capitilize the C in onClick. That might help. That's how I learned it, anyway.

Comment: I learned it that way too but apparently it doesnt make a difference

Comment: Some other relevant information on window.print() here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268840/determine-whether-browser-supports-printing