# window.print() not working on mobiles and ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a site in Laravel and in that I am providing a functionality to print certain pages. I am using `window.print()` for that. It's working fine on desktops , but its not working on mobiles and ipad ? Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using window.print() or alternative on Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684190/using-window-print-or-alternative-on-android-devices)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that of Browser Compatibility. Most likely the browser being used in the mobiles and iPad do not support the `window.print` method. You can check the Browser Compatibility for `window.print` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print)

For alternatives to `window.print` you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26771333/9971482).