# Firefox window.print() android

Tags: javascript, android

Has the window.print and all jquery print functions been revoked from  firefox android platform?
I am not able to use window.print() with firefox on android.
The script works.fine.with other browsers.

Comment: you can read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684190/using-window-print-or-alternative-on-android-devices

Comment: window.print is supported on android with chrome and edge but not firefox i believe. I need to enable silent printing on client side so i believe the straight forward method is using FF.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684190/using-window-print-or-alternative-on-android-devices.

Comment: No solution for this. The aim is to print silently on android devices as this is a POS app. Any ideas?