# window.print is not working for android & ios devices & any ideas to solve this problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('button.print').click(function(e) {
window.print();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button class="print">Print this page</button>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I print with this code, for both android and iOS. Is there any solution in JavaScript and/or JQuery ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684190/using-window-print-or-alternative-on-android-devices

Answer (score 0):

You can use GCP (Google Cloud Print)

https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/gadget

Comment: Plzz accept the answer if helpful so other can also use this