# How to auto fire key combination Ctrl P from asp.net code?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How to auto fire key combination Ctrl+P from asp.net code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript: window.print();

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.print

To my knowledge, it's not actually standard, though people have been using it for a really long time.  seealso: [cross-browser print command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458948/cross-browser-print-command)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way will be a button with the javascript function `window.print()`:

In your asp.net markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="printButton" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick="javascript:window.print();" />
```

For more information you can look at [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp) or have a look at [this code project site](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/351577/How-to-print-in-asp-net) there are different solution to print sites