# Window.print() function is not working properly in all browser

Tags: javascript, css

When I try to use `Window.print()` function that works good as I want in Google Chrome but same thing not working good in Mozilla Firefox. Here are some screenshots of the problem which is persisting. What's the problem here? and also how to remove default header and footer from print of Firefox because its works good in chrome

Html View of Report on Web:
[image: Html View of Report on Web]

View when do Print in Mozilla Firefox
[image: View when do Print in Mozilla Firefox]

[image: How to Remove default header and footer from firefox print]

Comment: I am not sure how this ties in with c#?

Comment: it has nothing to do with C#, as window.print() is pure javascript function.. also, it seems issue with your alignment and margins, window.pint() is working fine as you are getting reports on both browser.

Comment: I am Using this for Print 
`<style type="text/css" media="print">

        @page {
            size: A4 Landscape;
            margin-top: 1cm;
        margin-bottom: 1cm;
        }
        @media print {
            html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
         }

        }
    </style>`  @MohammadDehghan

Comment: And Just On Ready Load Window.Print Function

$(document).ready(function () {
            window.print();
        });

Its Work Good In Chrome but not in Firefox

Comment: In order to help you, please provide some test case(fiddle or codepen, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Browsers render differently by default. 
So [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458948/cross-browser-print-command) might help in custom print CSS styling.

If still some problem persists, post that part of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CSS to see if that fixes it.

```
* {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

You may need to experiment with `overflow-x` instead of `overflow` and applying to only the print media query.

Answer (score 0):

try using some plugins to export your report into proper format.. ex. PDFMake.js